# Agregar el bucle while a un código ya hecho

Tags: python, while

Estoy prácticamente iniciando en todo esto de la programación y Python, me encontré con un problema que decia lo siguiente: convertir el programa dado para que funcione mientras que el usuario responda "SI" a la pregunta "continua?"
Como dije, no tengo mucho conocimiento porque empecé hace unos dias.
Este es el código dado, donde tengo que implementar **solamente el bucle while**

````
a=int(input('ingresar el primer numero: '))
b=int(input('ingresar el segundo numero: '))
c=int(input('ingresar el tercer numero: '))
suma=a+b+c
print('la suma de los números es: ', suma)
promedio=(a+b+c)/3
if promedio<5:
   print('el promedio es mayor que 5')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que entiendo tu duda y te voy a intentar responder.

El bucle while evalúa una condición, por ejemplo si quiero implementar una cosa hasta que una variable sea diferente o tenga diferente valor... utilizaremos un while.

Para que te quede claro te haré un ejemplo en pseudocodigo:

1.- Quiero contar hasta diez:

```
 int variableContador=0;
 while(variableContador<10){
  variableContador++;
  }
```

En este ejemplo lo que haremos será ir sumando 1 a nuestra variableContador, hasta que esta sea mayor que 10.

En tu ejemplo podemos declarar una variable booleana continuar, y quedaría así:

```
boolean continuar=true; //declaramos el boleano y lo inicializamos a true
while(continuar){ //como continuar=true, entrará en el bucle

a=int(input('ingresar el primer numero: '))
b=int(input('ingresar el segundo numero: '))
c=int(input('ingresar el tercer numero: '))
suma=a+b+c
print('la suma de los números es: ', suma)
promedio=(a+b+c)/3
if promedio<5:
   print('el promedio es mayor que 5')

print('Quieres seguir?')
 //leemos la entrada
 if(si){
  //no tocamos nada ya que nuestra variable continuar ya esta en true y volverá ha entrar
 }else{
   continuar=false; // y saldremos del bucle
   }

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, te lo he hecho en pseudocodigo porque no he programado en python pero la idea es esta.

Comment: Hola Macia Salva, si por algo se caracteriza Python es por intentar ser ser lo más legible posible para humanos, tu pseudocódigo es casi código Python válido. Cambiando false/true por False/True y las llaves por niveles de sangrado lo tienes hecho.

Comment: Si quieres agregarlo para completar la respuesta te lo dejo con los mencionados cambios: [Try it Online](https://tio.run/##dVJBTsMwELz7FUt7SKJWINRGQEXFjTsSH3CdpV3J8QY7piq/4Rtc@7CwcUNbCZqDFe3OzI5n3ezaDbtZ1xl2LbmoPSzh1UeEcYXGaq9rDoAWVmxRO4YdWAZyZEhb@kxdDa0Q1HZDFuGos4Cx4ZpPhWWPmgK61mu//5KfpBuNRQXyaZlMrs3JNbHNM3Jrj0H8CKjxVKMHF@XkBWRFkRiry4yA6@gq/kMxlyktevPPkBDr3pmGicybgElFMSQimdWHdoWSSgC3/@65klcQ/jT1igHPNVbEIpQflQq4gVlq09sJ8QjlIhVPY1ICQxsD1HrHHt5lR2VWqIQdg0XsdyGOUsCVhkaWBx9yo0A9mPzZcg43k4zIp0BSGC@RUNIY6k9ZcW15iz4vfj0OhKsljAKNji7h/O08axuw6@aqVHcqkLpXD@p2rhz/AA). Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, no conozco muy bien el lenguaje de python, yo programa en Java, por eso he dicho lo de pseudocodigo, por que no estaba del todo seguro si el código que iba a poner era del todo correcto para el compilador. Un saludo.